# How to make the powershell line-buffered in emacs for Windows

Tags: powershell, emacs, command-line

I want to use powershell in emacs, but it seems that the powershell in emacs is block buffered. For example, when I write the a simple c program like this:

```
int main()
{
 printf("input the number of a value: \n");
 scanf("%d", &num);
}
```

I compile it and make it run in Powershell under emacs. It won't print out the line `input the number of a value:` until I input a number and hit `Enter`.  the c program runs well in powershell outside the emacs. My question is how can I run the PowerShell line buffered in emacs?

**edit** I use the [Powershell.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Powershell.el)

Answer (score 1):

The `stdout` of the C library is line buffered if the `stdout` of your program is connected to a terminal.  The reason you find the behavior in your original program (without `fflush`) is simply because while running through the GNU EMACS, your program thinks it is not connected to a real terminal.  Experiment running your program in `M-x term` or `M-x ansi-term`, for example.  The solutions given here suggest you using `fflush`, which is definitely not a solution as you won't change every little program that uses the C library in your system.  So the answer to your question is really giving your GNU EMACS a real terminal and not changing your program.  Now, the [bad news is that neither of these terminals for the GNU EMACS seem to work on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263012).  (Sorry.)  (Nevertheless, [it appears someone claims to run `ansi-term` on Windows](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/6t9d8t/emacs_shell_and_ansiterm_on_windows/).)

Answer (score 0):

You need to `fflush` before the `fscanf`.

Comment: When I `fflush` before the `fscanf`, it will flush twice and have exactly two same output.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with `eshell`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int num;
  printf("input the number:\n");
  fflush(stdout);
  scanf("%d", &num);
  printf("inc: %d\n", num + 1);
}
```

I couldn't reproduce your problem with `powershell.el` because I see another: it doesn't wait for the input, "reads" a 0 instead, prints "inc: 1" and exits.

Comment: is it your answer? or you come across the same question? I run your code in the emacs under powershell. it did the same like you have described:it doesn't wait for the input, "reads" a 0 instead, prints "inc: 1" and exits.

Comment: it works well in the cmdproxy which is a program included in the `GNU Emacs for windows`, maybe something should be done in the powershell.el

Comment: It's a partial answer: your code in the question behaved exactly as you described when compiled and run from `eshell` (I also had to declare `int num`, or it didn't compile). The code I posted does run in `eshell` and behave as expected. The problem with `powershell.el` must be a separate issue.